# Pygame nested while loop: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: python, while-loop, pygame

I am using pygame with pyscripter and pyopengl, and am trying to put a while loop inside the main while loop, but as soon as the game enters the inner loop, it repeats the loop forever and I can't get out

```
running = True
while running:
    keys=pygame.key.get_pressed()

    ## do game stuff

    if keys[K_l]:
        a=True
        while a:
            keys2=pygame.key.get_pressed()
            ## do something
            print a
            if keys2[K_p]:
                a = False
                break

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT or keys[K_ESCAPE]:
            running = False
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
```

After pressing l, this continuously prints `True` even if I press p

How can I exit the inside loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **call [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) inside your inner `while` loop** to ensures that your program can internally interact with the rest of the operating system.

```
# ....
while a:
    pygame.event.pump()
    keys2 = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    # do something ...
```

---

An alternative would be to **listen for `pygame.KEYDOWN` events** on the event queue in your game loop:

```
running = True
l_KeyPressed = False

while running:
    # get events from the queue
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN :
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                running = False

            if event.key == pygame.K_l:
                # do something
                l_KeyPressed = True

            if event.key == pygame.K_p and lPressed:
                l_KeyPressed = False
```

Hope this helps :)